# How can i see traffic souces in YouTube

Tags: traffic, youtube

How can i see the traffic sources from YouTube Analytics ex:Fb, Twitter

Is there any other tools to find the sources

Answer (score 1):

Connect your YouTube channel to your Google Analytics account.

1. sign into youtube, go to the account settings page
2. from your account page, select "view additional features"(https://www.youtube.com/features)
3. in the channel tab, select the "Advanced" option (https://www.youtube.com/advanced_settings)
4. After completing the final step below, insert your Google Analytics tracking ID in the designated field at the bottom of the page, and click save.

Make sure that you have admin access to a Google Analytics account, and create a new property for your YouTube Channel. This will give you a unique tracking ID to integrate with your Youtube channel.